# Rearrange Boolean expression by replacing brackets

Tags: boolean-expression

I was trying to check online if there is any equivalent expression to 1. (A AND B) OR C, by removing the brackets and rearranging the operands and boolean operators in the above expression.

Like 2. (A OR B) AND C = A AND C OR B AND C.

If I try to solve the first expression with the same logic as above, it doesn't seem logically equivalent I. E.  A OR C AND B OR C . I want to remove the brackets from the expression. That's my main aim

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "remove the brackets"?

When you write
(A OR B) AND C = A AND C OR B AND C
what does mean "A AND C OR B AND C"?
Does it means
A AND (C OR B) AND C
or
(A AND C) OR (B AND C)

Probably the latter, but it is only because you see **implicit** brackets around the AND expressions.
One generally considers that "AND" has a higher priority (precedence in programming languages) than "OR". Like "×" has a higher priority than "+".
and
a×b+c
is generally not ambiguous in terms of interpretation.

And it is true that "×" can be distributed over a sum, while the opposite is not true.

But there is no such thing in boolean algebra, and "AND" and "OR" have similar properties.
And they have the same distributivity.

So if your question is
"can we distribute an "OR" over an "AND" expression?",
the answer is yes.
(A AND B) OR C = (A OR C) AND (B OR C)
(just consider what happens when C=0 and when C=1 to verify that it is true)

If your question is
"does such an expression can be expressed without parenthesis *with the rule that AND expressions are implicitely surrounded by parenthesis*?",
the answer is also yes. Just write
A AND B OR C
with the precedence rule, it is interpreted as
(A AND B) OR C
You can also write
A.B+C
to make clearer that "AND" is generally considered as equivalent to  "×" and "OR" equivalent to "+" in terms of precedence.

And in programming languages like C, when one writes
`A & B | C`
it is clearly interpreted as
`(A & B) | C`
and the same is true for
`A && B || C`

So with the "implicit parenthesis around AND expressions" rule, you can write

A AND B OR C = (A OR C) AND (B OR C)
(A OR B) AND C = A AND C OR B AND C
Note that in either case, you need parenthesis in one side of the equality.